pom.xml is indicating end of support for products that have been upgraded. how do i fix this
I have a simple and main:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
   xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>ws-daley</groupId>
   <artifactId>test</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.0</version>
</project>

package ws.daley.test;
    
public class TestPom {
    public static void main(String[] strings) {
    }
}

MacOS 13.6.9
Spring Tool Suite 4.22.1 (Eclipse 4.31)
pom.xml, line 1, position 1 is flagged with the following errors:
Warning: Commercial support for Spring Boot 2.0.x ended on 2020-06-01
Warning: OSS support for Spring Boot 2.0.x ended on 2019-03-01
Info: Newer minor version of Spring Boot available: 2.7.18

Update: this project was formed by copying a large project and deleting everything I didn't need. I got the results above. Later I was playing around with the pom and copied the "Effective POM" to the top of the original file after commenting out the original so that I could look around to see what the error might be. Finding nothing, I did a couple of undos to get back to the original pom and lo and behold, the error was gone. I tried the same thing in my original large project, but only managed to move the error to the last line: 

you probably just need to reload project or maven reload (whatever the button is for that in spring-tool-suite so that it reloads the changes made in pom.xml. Also if it is anything like eclipse, don't forget to manually save (Ctrl + s) the file you edited.

since it is eclipse based: right click on the project, go to maven -> update project, then select your project and hit OK

This validation is coming as part of the Spring tooling and can be disabled or customized to your needs in the Preferences -> Spring -> Validation -> Versions and Support Ranges. So if things go wrong, you could just disable this as a quick fix.
One additional problem might be that there is outdated information read from the cache of those validations. You can delete the cache via:

exit the IDE
delete everything from <userhome>/.sts4/.symbolCache
restart your IDE

I am still wondering why the validation shows up the information about Spring Boot 2.x versions, so it would be great if you could create an issue for that at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and attach a sample project that reproduces this.
In addition to all that, please also update to the latest version of the Spring Tools for Eclipse.

Thanks! This fixed it. Unfortunately I fixed it before I saved the project to add it to the issues.
